# Using Common Lisp Apache fastcgi

Tags: apache, common-lisp, fastcgi, sbcl, clisp

Concerning a web app, using Common Lisp, Apache, and fastcgi can one match urls with the desired functions defined in top-level rather than writing separate script files per urls?

Is it possible to use both approach above in a development environment of Common Lisp Apache fastcgi combination? And how, by which tools?

Is it compulsory to use a server which is loaded on Common Lisp implementation (as described and mentioned as "simple-server" in [this page presents sb-fastcgi](http://kdr2.net/sb-fastcgi.html#sb-fastcgi))  in a development environment of Common Lisp Apache fastcgi combination? Or it is not compulsory on SBCL Apache sb-fastcgi environment and "simple-server" mentioned there is just another way? I try to avoid a server like those and some others that is not as well supported and maintained as Apache.

Does fastcgi make the connection between Interpreter (a Common Lisp here) and Apache directly or via another server software loaded on Common Lisp, say like Hunchentoot or "simpleserver" mentioned?

I want to have both of above top mentioned approaches and to be able to run Common Lisp with Apache via fastcgi? What tools i need as sufficiently necessary?

Comment: I can only say that you *want* to have a Lisp server running independently of Apache server, otherwise you won't be able to use it for anything remotely serious due to a very long start-up time it would take on *every* request. This is what `sb-fastcgi:simple-server` does. I don't know whether there is a way by using `sb-fastcgi` to bind requests to functions, but you probably can come up with some sort of `defhandler` macro to do that relatively easily on your own. (You'd need to examine the request object and call a handler from some dispatch table you create).

Comment: thank you very much, i have difficulties in setting a habitat for Common Lisp, and have difficulties in finding help or documentation in this, and find this surprising. Anyway. Regarding your comment i want a lisp server running independently of apache server, is this the same thing that is done with Clisp and its FastCGI interface. in general I want to be clarified in
1. Is this separate server already exists in other fastcgi implementations implicitly, and it is just seen in sb-fastcgi explicitly say as a design choice of its API? Is it the general way that fastcgi protocol is implemented?

Comment: 2.about fastcgi it is written generally that it does not load a script each time a request is made but so it differs from cgi which loads every time, isn't that contrary to things you said about load times above.

Comment: AFAIK fastcgi is an alternative to what Apache httpd *_mode would usually do. I.e. it implies that the runtime remains loaded, and it invokes some handlers in that runtime in response to incoming traffic. In my experience the most common setup is to use Apache htpd / nginx as a proxy / cache server and run eg. Hunchentoot behind it as an application server. http://blog.ponto-dot.com/2009/08/18/hunchentoot-behind-proxy-server/ this post looks like a pretty decent explanation of how to achieve that.

Comment: i think besides the way u described and pointed there must be a way to use clisp+its fastcgi interface with apache+fastcgi but their page nothing describes hoe to set the environment. again that is the case with common lisp. u can master it but more difficult is to set an environment with possibilities or at least one, incorporate it into an install and go use it situation. if i success i will make everything to automize it in a batteries included, ready to go fashion, i promise to entire humanity :). what a situation.

Comment: Do you think such an environment you mentioned above would be a performant, stable and reliable one for a business  with a high traffic website? i mainly doubt Hunchentoot. but the first things i ve mentioned above about url to function dispatching table exists in hunchentoot, this is just for usability preference.

Comment: Some use Node.js as their HTTP servers... in comparison, Hunchentoot isn't such a bad idea at all. I've not seen a site to manage large amounts of traffic running Lisp, so I can't tell if this setup will manage it, but I can't also find any counterargument, so, why not? Your first question: well, there are quite a lot of people who know Apache httpd insides quite well, it's often extended, so, maybe the authors of sb-fastcgi hoped that whoever will use it will know how to set things up? Maybe, if you want more docs, look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI in the language binding section.

Comment: I would recommend using CLACK with ningle or lucerne using the fastcgi backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Clack](http://clacklisp.org/) for all web-development in lisp now. 
With [Caveman2](http://8arrow.org/caveman/) you will have a pleasant lisp web experience :)

As the web documentation states:

> The reason why Clack had only a few bugs so far is plenty of quality
>   unit tests. There are 173 tests currently. The test coverage has been
>   kept over 70% since its first official release.
>
> All releases have passed the test suite on three CL implementations:
>   Clozure CL, SBCL, and CLISP. You can check the current status at
>   http://ci.clacklisp.org/.